# .NET MAUI - Camera.MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I am new to mobile development and I recently watched tutorial video about taking pictures using Camera.MAUI - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlZSLPf22vI . I have a project that needs to capture photo then save it to mssql database, I already have an API on saving image details with byte data type and I am able to connect it to my maui app.

My problem is, I don't know how to save the captured photo.

Below is my initial code:

```
<VerticalStackLayout
 Spacing="25"
Padding="30,0"
VerticalOptions="Fill"
HorizontalOptions="Fill">

   <cv:CameraView x:Name="cameraView" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" Cameras ="{Binding ViewCameraCommand}"/>

    <Button Text="Smile!" Command="{Binding CapturePhotoCommand}"/>

    <Image Source="{Binding ImgSrc}" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" />

    <Button Margin="20" Text="Save Photo" Command="{Binding SavePhotoCommand}"/>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

```
  [ObservableProperty] public int _imgId;
 [ObservableProperty] public string _imgName;
 [ObservableProperty] public string _imgData;
 [ObservableProperty] public string _loc;
 [ObservableProperty] public string _owner;
 [ObservableProperty] public byte[] _imgView;
 [ObservableProperty] public string _imgType;

 [ObservableProperty] public CameraView _cameraView;
 [ObservableProperty] ImageSource _imgSrc;

 IPhotoDataService photoDataService;
 public HomeViewModel(IPhotoDataService photoDataService)
 {
     this.photoDataService = photoDataService;
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 async Task Tap()
 {
     //TODO: refresh page without details
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");

 }

 [RelayCommand]
 async Task SavePhoto()
 {
     try
     {
         var addPhoto = new PhotoModel
         {
             ImageId = ImgId,
             ImageName = ImgName,
             ImageData = ImgData,
             Location = Loc,
             User = Owner,
             ImageType = ImgType,
             //ImageView = ImgView,
         };

         Debug.WriteLine("---> Add New Item");
         await photoDataService.AddPhotoAsync(addPhoto);
         await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Information", "Successfully addded", "Ok");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
     }
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 async Task ViewCamera()
 {
     CameraView.Camera = CameraView.Cameras.First();

     MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
     {
         await CameraView.StopCameraAsync();
         await CameraView.StartCameraAsync();

     });
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 async Task CapturePhoto()
 {
     ImgSrc = CameraView.GetSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG);
 }
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI?tab=readme-ov-file#using-cameraview) - section labeled “Take a Photo”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is, I don't know how to save the captured photo.

It is recommended that you use [Media picker for photos and videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) to implement this feature.
The [IMediaPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.media.imediapicker?view=net-maui-8.0) interface lets a user pick or take a photo or video on the device.

We can call the [CapturePhotoAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.media.imediapicker.capturephotoasync?view=net-maui-8.0) method to open the camera and let the user take a photo. If the user takes a photo, the return value of the method will be a non-null value.

The following code sample uses the media picker to take a photo and save it to the cache directory:

```
public async void TakePhoto()
{
    if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
    {
        FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            // save the file into local storage
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

            using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

And from the tip mentioned in above document, we could know that:

> The `FullPath` property doesn't always return the physical path to the
> file. To get the file, use the `OpenReadAsync` method.